# Return all the images's likes on foreach loop with Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i've been working on a project for a while now using CodeIgniter and i've been fighting with an issue for several days. I'm displaying a series of images from the database with a foreach loop on the index view and each image you can like or dislike, and this works fine, the problem is that  the page only displays the amount of likes for one image. So i figured that the solution would be to send the data to the public function `index()` method on my controller and then make a query in the model and return all to the view. You think there is another way to pull this off?

This is my ajax **request**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var id = $("*#id_image").val();
     $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php/inicio/display_votes_index',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {id_image: id},
        success: function (response) {
            $("#displayVote"+id).html(response.msg + " puntos");
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

This is my **view**

```
<aside class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-8">
        <?php 
        foreach ($images as $value) {
            ?><h1 style="font-size:20px;"><a href="#"><?= $value->title; ?></a></h1><?php
            ?><img src="<?= base_url(); ?>images/<?= $value->path; ?>" alt="<?= $value->title ?>" class="img-responsive" width="500"/>
            <a href="#" style="color: #636363; margin-top:10px;display:block" id="displayVote<?= $value->id_image; ?>"></a><br/>
            <button type="button" style="margin-right:5px;" class="btn btn-default btn-md" onclick="voteUp(<?= $value->id_image; ?>)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></button>
            <button type="button" style="margin-right:5px;" class="btn btn-default btn-md"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
            <button type="button" style="margin-right:5px;" class="btn btn-default btn-md"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span></button>
            <input type="hidden" id="id_image" value="<?= $value->id_image; ?>"/>
            <hr/>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</aside>
```

This is the **model**

```
public function get_all_votes($id_image)
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(vote) AS vote_up FROM likes WHERE id_image = ? AND id_status = 1";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $id_image);
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row->vote_up;
}
```

And this is the **controller** recieving the data

```
public function display_votes_index()
{
    $id_image = $this->input->post('id_image');
    $votes = $this->vote_model->get_all_votes($id_image);
    if ($votes) {
        echo json_encode(['success' => TRUE, 'msg' => $votes]);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['success' => FALSE, 'msg' => 'Error']);
    }
}
```

PD: if i use `eq()` like this: `var id = $("#id_image").eq(1).val();` the page shows the amount of likes of the second image in the loop, and if i change the numbers displays the likes for the other images. Is there a way to select all the id's of all the images? i tried with `eq(*)` but it didn't work. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change hidden field on HTML as:

```
<input type="hidden" CLASS="id_image" id="id_image_<?= $value->id_image; ?>" value="<?= $value->id_image; ?>"/>
```

And JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".id_mage").each(function(i) {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php/inicio/display_votes_index',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {id_image: id},
            success: function (response) {
                $("#displayVote"+id).html(response.msg + " puntos");
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Above solution makes more ajax call than. So the best solution is use one ajax call, and model will return all votes of all images. And js will put the vote to the right image then.